# How to add radiobuttons to a submenu in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, submenu, menubar

I want to have a set of two radiobuttons "BBC" and "CNN" in a submenu named "Channel" in my GUI.
I tried to use the `add_radiobutton` method, but the radiobuttons appear under the submenu, while I want them to behave as attributes for the "Channel" submenu, rather than additional submenus of the "News" menu.

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("main")
root.geometry("500x500")


MAIN_MENU = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=MAIN_MENU)

File_menu = Menu(MAIN_MENU, tearoff=0)
MAIN_MENU.add_cascade(label="News", menu=File_menu, underline=0)
File_menu.add_command(label="Channel")

File_menu.add_radiobutton(label="BBC")
File_menu.add_radiobutton(label="CNN")

Settings_menu = Menu(MAIN_MENU, tearoff=0)
MAIN_MENU.add_cascade(label="History", menu=Settings_menu, underline=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: are you wanting menu to pop up to the right of `Channel` with the options BBC, CNN as a side menu?

Comment: Exactly at right  side.

Comment: You are explicitly adding them to the file menu. Why do you expect them to show up somewhere else? Have you tried adding them to the menu you want them to be on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must make a submenu first, add the radiobuttons to it, and then add it as a cascade to your main menu. Then, add that menu to your menu bar.

```
menuBar = tk.Menu(root)
menu1 = tk.Menu(root)
submenu = tk.Menu(root)
submenu.add_radiobutton(label="Option 1")
submenu.add_radiobutton(label="Option 2")

menuBar.add_cascade(label="Menu 1", menu=menu1)
menu1.add_cascade(label="Subemnu with radio buttons", menu=submenu)
```

Full working example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

menuBar = tk.Menu(root)
menu1 = tk.Menu(root)
submenu = tk.Menu(root)
submenu.add_radiobutton(label="Option 1")
submenu.add_radiobutton(label="Option 2")

menuBar.add_cascade(label="Menu 1", menu=menu1)
menu1.add_cascade(label="Subemnu with radio buttons", menu=submenu)

root.config(menu=menuBar)
root.mainloop()
```

You'll probably want to add some attributes to your radiobuttons.
A more complete form would be:

```
add_radiobutton(label="Option 1", value=1, variable=optionVar, command=on_option_1)
```

Where:

- `label` is the text that appears in the menu;
- `variable` is a `tk.Variable` instance, generally an `IntVar` or a `StringVar`;
- `value` is the value to set to `variable` when the option is selected;
- `command` is the callback to be run when the option is selected.

Comment: Working as expected but my underline is not working can suggest any procedure to solve this.Thank you

Comment: @Right leg : After providing attributes "variable", user option selection  goes to multiple select, whereas only one option needed to be select.